# Layout for a Booking App

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I have a project which will be a portal to book a conference room. It will be a private app that will be run on a cheap tablet and mounted in the conference room. The app will just update a webserver backend.

I would like to implement a UI that is essentially a grid. The day of the week will be on the x axis and the hours on the y axis. If a particular time has already been books a different color will show. To book the room you press on the cell that corresponds to the day and time you would like and asks to confirm this.

I have played around with a grid view and table layout and can't find anything that fits the bill so suggestions are most welcome.

I have not used openGL yet would this be a good opportunity to learn about it?

Comment: What was particularly wrong with using `TableLayout` in your case?

Comment: @Xion setting headers on the top of the tablet seemed to be problematic and setting lines down the tablet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could accomplish a layout like that. Personally I am a fan of using RelativeLayouts. They usually tend to require a little bit more to get setup looking how you want. But it is far easier down the line if you decide you want to make any non-trivial changes to the layout. openGL would allow you to do this, but I think you are better off using the layouts and views provided already. At the very most maybe you'll want to create your own subclass of View that fits your needs see [Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) if you want more info on that.